# How to access relations before create in model using octobercms?

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-backend

Remember, first of all, this is related to octobercms (laravel) - http://octobercms.com

I am doing something before creating an record.. My crud is already working with relations. My structure is this: Coupom coupom_categories Categories

I want list all those categories selected in the crud to make something with then before create coupom..

in the category, i have a field called "last_date_added_coupom", so i want update those dates to mark the date the coupom i added, so, i dont need to use left join each coupom to find latest one

Any help?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe reading this helps: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#deferred-binding

Comment: What exatly do you want to do?

Comment: in the category, i have a field called "last_date_added_coupom", so i want update those dates to mark the date the coupom i added, so, i dont need to use left join each coupom